# calling a function inside itself doesn't work as it should in python

Tags: python, function, recursion

hello i have a real world problem to solve.
i have list of woods lengths (in cm). i want to put them in boxes
each box has 4 rows , we can put woods in a row as long as the total length doesn't exceed 140 cm. but there is an exception if one wood is longer than 140 cm we can put it in an empty row. i need to return 3 thing from my function:

1. index of row
2. start point of each wood in a row
3. box index

my function works for the first box , but when  box is full and i reset the box inside my function and call itself again something cause an issue and the outcome is none or false.

```
my_woods = [50, 60, 70, 40, 30, 120, 90, 50, 70, 70, 60, 30, 45, 25, 40, 45, 150, 60, 70, 80, 25, 40, 80]
row_length = 140

box = [[], [], [], []]
box_idx = 1

def addtobox(length, box, box_idx):
    for idx, row in enumerate(box):
        if row == []:
            row.append(length)
            return idx, sum(row) - length, box_idx
        else:
            sum_row = sum(row)
            if row_length - sum(row) >= length:
                row.append(length)
                return idx, sum(row) - length , box_idx
    box = [[], [], [], []]
    box_idx += 1
    addtobox(length, box, box_idx)

for wood in my_woods:
    print(addtobox(wood, box, box_idx))
    
# Result

# (0, 0, 1)
# (0, 50, 1)
# (1, 0, 1)
# (1, 70, 1)
# (0, 110, 1)
# (2, 0, 1)
# (3, 0, 1)
# (3, 90, 1) # the last correct result
# None
# None
# None
# (1, 110, 1)
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
# None
```

Comment: Do you mean `return addtobox(length, box, box_idx)` ?

Comment: unhelpful comment: recursion is probably not the best approach here: consider using `while` instead

Comment: @DietrichEpp that doesn't work either

Answer (score -1):

MAYBE you can try something like change, *inside your function*, this:

```
box = [[], [], [], []]
```

into this:

```
box.clear()
box = [[], [], [], []]
```

Hope it can help

Comment: What is that meant to change? `box` gets reassigned in the next line.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).